# How to mirror an image file? (2.2+)

Tags: android, image, image-manipulation

I have a PNG file that I want to use for an overlay - however, this file has to be mirrored (and rotated by 180°), but in order to save space, I don't want to place the mirrored file in the apk, but do this action programmatically.

How can I do this with Froyo and above?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scaling by -1.0 causes the image to be flipped. Assuming `bmp` is the bitmap you want to mirror (here on the x axis) you can do :

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); 
Bitmap mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.width(), bmp.height(), matrix, false);
```

If you don't want to create a second bitmap, you can do the same with `canvas.scale` :

```
canvas.save();
canvas.scale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, ...); // The bitmap is flipped
canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use View.setScaleX()

For example

```
 public void mirrorView(View v){
    v.setScaleX(-1.0f);
}
```

Comment: It's really the best option